# Overlap div tags over shockwave player

Tags: css, overlay, overlapping, shockwave

I have modal(Html Div tags) which will be prompted when user click  a(logout) button.

My Modal is working fine in all the pages except the page where Shockwave player exists.
Shockwave player is overlaping the modal dialog.

I would like my Modal Dialog to overlap the shockwave movie.

I tried placing

Tried z-Index and it didnt work.

Note: I am using IE 9
 position:relative;

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ande/de3Wn/8/)

Below is the code I use

```
     <input type="submit" name="Logout" value="Logout" id="logout"/>
<div id=shockwave> 

<object width="800px" height="600px" id="DcrObj" name="DcrObj" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/director/sw.cab"
            classid="clsid:166B1BCA-3F9C-11CF-8075-444553540000" >
                              <param name="swStretchStyle" value="meet" />
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
            <param value= "xxxx.dcr" name="src"/>
            <embed  width="100%" height="100%"  src="xxx.dcr" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/"
                type="application/x-director" PlayerVersion="11" swLiveconnect="True" swStretchStyle="meet" wmode="opaque"/> @*wmode="opaque"*@
                    </object>
</div>

---Modal Code
  <div id='confirm'>
            <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
            <div class='message'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
            </div>
</div>


 $('#logout').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        confirm("@Resources.msgAreYouSureYouWantToLogOut", function () {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';
        });
    })
```

Comment: if you can make a Fiddle

Comment: wmode=opaque should be doing it, unless the #shockwave div is in a different positioning other than the #confirm div...are both in relative positioning? The position type has to be the same for z-index to work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Please find below link for Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ande/de3Wn/5/

Comment: Can any one please answer my question....